# Spring-Boot and Spock fail when using Unroll

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spock, unroll

I'm setting up a demo project with Spring-Boot. For entity-persistence, I'm using Spring generated Repository implementations based on interfaces:

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long> {

    List<Movie> findByNameContaining(String name);
    List<Movie> findByRelease(LocalDate release);
    List<Movie> findByReleaseBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end);
    List<Movie> findByNameContainingAndRelease(String name, LocalDate release);
}
```

To test this, I'm using Spock with Groovy, which works wonders:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
class MovieRepositoryTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    MovieRepository movieRepository

    @Test
    def findByNameContaining_shouldFindCorrectMovies() {
        given:
        movieRepository = this.movieRepository

        when:
        def result = movieRepository.findByNameContaining("Iron Man")

        then:
        result.size() == 3
    }
}
```

But as soon as I try to mix in Spock's @Unroll, everything falls apart:

```
@Test
@Unroll
def findByNameContaining_shouldFindCorrectMovies() {
    given:
    movieRepository = this.movieRepository

    when:
    def result = movieRepository.findByNameContaining(query)

    then:
    result.size() == expected

    where:
    query       ||  expected
    "Iron Man"  ||  3
    "Hulk"      ||  1
    "Thor"      ||  3
    "Avengers"  ||  3
    "Thanos"    ||  0
    ""          ||  20
}
```

Results in:

```
[INFO] Running com.spring.boot.demo.repositories.MovieRepositoryTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.spring.boot.demo.repositories.MovieRepositoryTest
[ERROR] initializationError(com.spring.boot.demo.repositories.MovieRepositoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: Method $spock_feature_0_0 should have no parameters
```

I'm out of clues to what may cause this.
Any help is welcome.
Thank you

Edit 1:
Well, this is interesting. I've tried the following:
* Remove @Test -> java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
* Remove @RunWith and @ContextConfiguration -> Unroll works, but movieRepository is not injected / wired: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method findByNameContaining() on null object

Fiddling with the different annotations hasn't resulted in a working scenario though. Any guesses?

Comment: Are you sure you need to put @Test on top of the method? I thought Spock didn't require that jUnit annotation...

Comment: I agree with @HansWesterbee, you don't need to use `@Test`. Not sure if it's the cause of an error though. Most likely `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and  `@ContextConfiguration` are obsolete as well. The `@SpringBootTest` annotation should be enough to start the context. Please remove them and try again. If it doesn't help what Spring Boot and Spock version are you using?

Comment: I mentioned it because the annotation could confuse the Groovy magic that Spock does.

Comment: That's worth a try. Will do that ASAP. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesss, I've got it:

The `RunWith` was the culprit. In my Edit1, I noticed the difference with removing `@Test`. That got me thinking that I may be confusing JUnit testing with Spock testing. Also, the `No runnable methods` got me thinking. And leaving out the `@RunWith` since it is mostly absent in other Spock & Spring examples seemed like a good idea. And having Spring beans wired up with `@ContextConfiguration` is quite nice ;-). Apparently, `@SpringBootTest` doesn't do this?